# Spring Java: How to get a matrix for success, failure for a task running in a threadpool

Tags: java, spring

I have a Job that is scheduled for every day. The job reads the data in batches from an API and submits the result that in a Spring ConcurrentTaskExecutor thread pool. The task defined in ConcurrentTaskExecutor, processes the data and writes that into DB.

Considering concurrent execution my question is how can I get a consolidated matrix like success, failures for the reader and processor

```
public class JobHandler{
   @Autowired
   Reader reader;
   //invoked once in a day
   public void execute(){
      reader.read();
     // Print the total read count and failures
     // Print the total process count and failures
   } 
}
@Component
public class Reader{
    @Autiwrired
    private ConcurrentTaskExecutor concurrentTaskExecutor;
    @Autiwrired
    private Processor processor;
    public void read(){

     while(true){
     //read the data from third partyAPI in batches
      try{
        processor.submit(()-> concurrentTaskExecutor.submit(processor.process()));
       if(//no results){
           break;
       }
      }catch(Exception e){
      } 
     }
  }
}
@Component
public class Processor{
    public void process(Data data){
     try{
       //read the data from third partyAPI in batches
      //do some operations and writes to DB
     }catch(Exception e){
     }
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use callback for getting result asynchronously. F.e.

```
public class JobHandler {
        @Autowired
        Reader reader;

        //invoked once in a day
        public void execute() {
            reader.read(
                    new ResultCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onRead(long success, long failures) {
                            // Print the total read count and failures
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProcess(long success, long failures) {
                            // Print the total process count and failures
                        }
                    }
            );
        }
    }

    public interface ResultCallback {
        void onRead(long success, long failures);
        void onProcess(long success, long failures);
    }

    @Component
    public class Reader {
        @Autiwrired
        private ConcurrentTaskExecutor concurrentTaskExecutor;
        @Autiwrired
        private Processor processor;

        public void read(ResultCallback callback) {

            while (true) {
                //read the data from third partyAPI in batches
                DataResult dataResult = ...;
                callback.onRead(dataResult.getSuccess(), dataResult.getFailure());
                Data data = dataResult.getData();
                try {
                    processor.submit(() -> concurrentTaskExecutor.submit(
                            (Runnable) () -> {
                                ProcessorResult processorResult = processor.process(data);
                                callback.onProcess(processorResult.getSuccess(), processorResult.getFailure());
                            }
                    ));
                    if (//no results){
                    break;
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
            }
        }
    }

    @Component
    public class Processor {
        public ProcessorResult process(Data data) {
            try {
                //read the data from third partyAPI in batches
                //do some operations and writes to DB
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are short on time - log failures and successes and then parse the logs with `zgrep | wc -l` (I assume you already have logging facility like log4j).

Given more time, rewrite it with spring-batch and get your statistics from spring-batch DB tables.

Comment: @JDev Was my answer helpful?